# ODP to Powerpoint Software?

Tags: conversion

Is there some sort of free and/or open source converter that could be used on a Linux or Windows server to convert ODP (Open Office presentations) into Powerpoint files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [oood](http://www.erp5.org/HowToUseOood), from Nexedi. I've used it under Linux to convert odt documents to various formats, but it can be made working also for odp to ppt; it is an xml-rpc server, and client with samples are provided in a number of languages.

A new version of this is [cloudooo](http://www.erp5.org/HowToUseCloudOOo), same company, but never actually tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just save the files in PowerPoint format from OpenOffice?

Comment: The files come in ODP, and I need them converted. These files aren't necessarily coming from Open Office directly and they need to be stored in ODP on my server before being downloaded in PPT.

Comment: There are some scripting facilities available through the Python integration which may be utilized to automate your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can run OpenOffice in a headless mode for doing batch conversions.

Comment: The idea makes sense, but it needs a sample command to make it useful.